# Which is the best way to mask a String in Java?

Tags: java, android, mask

I want to apply a mask on a String "96506550" but I'm getting 965065-50 instead of 96506-550

```
//my method
public String format(String data, String mask) {
        MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter(mask);        
        return mf.valueToString(data);
}

System.out.println(formatter.format("96506550","#####-###"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use

```
public void setPlaceholderCharacter(char placeholder)
```

This function sets the character to use in place of characters that are not present in the value, ie the user must fill them in. The default value is a space. This is only applicable if the placeholder string has not been specified, or does not completely fill in the mask.

That's the reason there is a single character placeholder error.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working.
mf.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');

Comment: Just in case anybody passing through here with an `Invalid Character` `ParseException`, adding this line solved the problem for me: `mf.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);`. In my case, my mask had not only dashes but dots as well. I'm not sure if that was the issue. All the rest is the same as this question with this answer's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `ParseException` (or throw it). Next, your `Formatter` won't accept input that isn't correctly formatted. Your input is eight digits, but your format expects five digits, a dash and then three digits. You could handle eight digits as a special case. Also, `MaskFormatter.valueToString(Object)` doesn't work like you hope (you can however validate by calling `MaskFormatter.stringToValue(String)` and passing that to the first function). Like,

```
public static String format(String data, String mask) throws ParseException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{8}");
    if (p.matcher(data).matches()) {
        return data.substring(0,5) + "-" + data.substring(5);
    }
    MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter(mask);
    return mf.valueToString(mf.stringToValue(data));
}
```